# Can sequences in two seperated sets have the same limit point?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A set $X$ is said to be seperated $\iff$ $\exists$ two subsets $A $ and $ B $ of $X$ such that $A \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset $, $B \cap cl(A) \neq \emptyset$ and $A \cup B =X$.

Now,we do not claim $cl(A) \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset $. Does this mean that, if there are two sequences each of them in two separated sets then they may converge to the same limit point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. Consider the sets $ (-1,0) $ and $ (0,1) $. These sets are separated, but we see that the sequences $ \{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\geq 1} $ and $ \{-\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\geq 1} $ both converge to $ 0 $.

Comment: But $X=(-1,0)\cup  (0,1) $ doesn't contain  $0$.

Comment: But $0$ belongs to the closure of each sets. Hence, we cannot claim $cl(A) \cap cl(B) \neq \emptyset$ for seperated sets. Right ?

Comment: @shakunimama. Right. If $A,B$ are separated then $cl(A)\cap cl(B)$ may or may not be empty.